# There is $\{x_n\}$, $x_n$ in $l^\infty$ such that $||x_n||_\infty \leq 1$, $||x_n - x||_\infty\rightarrow 0$, each $x_n$ has finite values

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken from Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis Chapter 3 section 7 problem 3.

Problem Statement:
Show that if $x \in l^\infty$, $||x||_\infty \leq 1$, then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$, $x_n$ in $l^\infty$ such that $||x_n||_\infty \leq 1$, $||x_n - x||_\infty\rightarrow 0$, and each $x_n$ takes on only a finite number of values.

I wanted to see if my solution below was correct. Any input is greatly appreciated

Let $M  = ||x||_\infty$. The $x(i) \in [-M, M]$. For any $\epsilon$ let us partition this interval into parts with length at most $2\epsilon$. Namely, we have the intervals $[-M, -M+2\epsilon)$, $[-M+2\epsilon, -M+4\epsilon)$,...$[-M+2(m-1)\epsilon, M]$, where $m$ is the number of intervals which exist in this partition such that each part have length at most $2\epsilon$. We can now construct our sequence $\{x_n\}$ as follows. For each $n$, let $\epsilon = 1/n$. By construction, $x(i)$ must belong to a unique interval. If this interval is of the form $[-M+2k\epsilon, -M+2(k+1)\epsilon]$ then let $x_n(i) = -M+(2k+1)\epsilon$. For the interval $[-M+2(m-1)\epsilon, M]$, let $x_n(i) = -M+(2m-1)\epsilon$. In each case, the value we picked is at most a distance $\epsilon$ from any point in the interval it belongs in. Since this is true for all $i$, it follows that $||x_n - x||_\infty\leq \epsilon$, and since $\epsilon = 1/n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, convergence follows. The values for $x_n(i)$ are contained in the interval $[-M, M]$ and since by assumption $M\leq 1$, it follows that $||x_n||\leq 1$. Finally, as there are a only a finite number of intervals, $x_n$ can only take on a finite number of values.

Comment: Looks good to me!